# How to access the object data that is stored in Tag property in a gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, radgridview

I am creating an application using winforms API and C#.

I have gridview, some of the rows have an object associated with a row. The object is stored in the `Tag` property like so

```
var tagObj = new AdditionalInfoPhoneActivations();
rowInfo.Tag = tagObj;
radGridView1.Rows.Add(rowInfo);
```

here is how I am trying to access the tag property which is not working

```
    void radGridView1_CommandCellClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var tagObj = new AdditionalInfoPhoneActivations();
        var x = (sender as CellFormattingEventArgs);
        tagObj = e.CellElement.Tag;

        Common.Alert("You ordered " + tagObj.serialNumber + " " + tagObj.saleType);
    }
```

This is the error that I am running into

```
Error   2   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CellElement' and no extension method 'CellElement' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\User\C# Projects\RM\RM\Register.cs 175 24  RM
```

Comment: You need to cast it to the type of thing you have put in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting to the wrong type. Also, you'll most likely have to access the row (RowElement) that the cell belongs to, and cast the `Tag` property (which is an `object` and can store anything) back to the type of object you originally stored in it.

```
var cell = (sender as GridCommandCellElement);

if (cell != null)
{
    var myTag = (AdditionalInfoPhoneActivations)cell.RowElement.RowInfo.Tag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)  for some reason it does not seems to be passing the object or something. I keep getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` the I try to display `myTag.serialNumber` I am not sure what is wrong