# How can I access data from a Tag in C#

Tags: c#, tags

I've seen this in other questions but I do not understand the answers.

I have a class, that gets filled by cycling through a SQL reader, and then an array of these objects is created and then buttons are created from that array of objects.  The code looks like this:

```
public class MenuItem
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Cost { get; set; }
   public string OrderListName { get; set; }

   public MenuItem() {}
}
```

The SQL loop is this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   MenuItem item = new MenuItem
   {
     Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
     OrderListName = reader["orderlistname"].ToString(),
     Cost = Convert.ToDouble(reader["cost"])
   };
   MenuItems[MenuItemCount] = item;
   MenuItemCount++;
}
```

And then I create buttons with this code inside a for loop

```
{
  Button menubutton = new Button
  {
   Text = MenuItems[k].Name + Globals.nl + MenuItems[k].Cost,
   Location = new Point(point1, point2),
   Size = new Size(100, 100),
   Visible = true,
   Tag = MenuItems[k]
};
 MenuButtons[j] = menubutton;
 j++;
 point1 += 110;
 point2 += 0;
}
```

In another for loop I have:

`MenuButtons[k].Click += new EventHandler(MenuButton_Click);`

and finally

```
private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Button button = sender as Button;
   }
```

So I create multiple objects based on SQL rows, save those objects into an array of Objects, and then create a button per object in the array.  I can access the button properties properly, but I can't figure out how to access the properties of the object saved in the tag property of the button.

I found this post, and believe the answer is there, but I can't figure it out:
[How to access the object data that is stored in Tag property in a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932680/how-to-access-the-object-data-that-is-stored-in-tag-property-in-a-gridview)

I can provide more code if you need to see more.
I've tried

```
Console.WriteLine((MenuItem)button.Tag.OrderListName)
```

which is inside the MenuButton_Click function

and other variations of that but they all lead to the same issue which is it says "Object does not contain a definition for OrderListName" and when I do just button.tag it just shows "Form1+MenuItem" when I click the button so that suggests the object isn't being broken down and accessed.

Comment: Try doing `Console.WriteLine(((MenuItem)button.Tag).OrderListName)`

Answer (score 0):

that is it `Console.WriteLine(((MenuItem)button.Tag).OrderListName)`